# Path has an invalid token XmlNode Select single node

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xmldocument

My code for selecting SingleNode

```
 var node=doc.SelectSingleNode("//Product[SKU=" + barcode + "]");
```

when I pass normal string like "123456" its working properly but for string containing '_'(Underscore) its throwing exception.

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '//Product[SKU=100238_0.5]' has an invalid token
```

Any Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
'//Product["SKU=100238_0.5"]'
```

Or:

```
"//Product['SKU=100238_0.5']"
```

Answer (score 1):

As underscore makes the string a non numeric value, it should be treated as a string inside the predicate...

```
var node=doc.SelectSingleNode("//Product[SKU='" + barcode + "']");
// Note the single quotes (SKU='')
```

The xpath expression should read, for example, like this:

```
//Product[SKU='100238_0.5'] or
//Product[SKU="100238_0.5"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing it as a string literal :

```
var node=doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//Product[SKU=" + barcode + "]");
```